# Call Lightbox with onClick Event

Tags: lightbox, lightbox2

I have a Gallery using an unordered list, like bellow:

```
<ul>
    <li style="background: center no-repeat #bc874c url(images/image-01.jpg)"></li>
    <li style="background: center no-repeat #bc874c url(images/image-02.jpg)"></li>
    <li style="background: center no-repeat #bc874c url(images/image-03.jpg)"></li>
    <li style="background: center no-repeat #bc874c url(images/image-04.jpg)"></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, I'm using the background of the element to show the image, so, I want to when the user clicks on the `li` element, a lightbox opens, is that possible?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can put an onclick event in each LI but it would be easier to just put the href links inside each li..

```
<ul>
   <li onclick="alert('here');" style="background: center no-repeat #bc874c url(images/image-01.jpg)"></li>
   <li style="background: center no-repeat #bc874c url(images/image-02.jpg)"></li>
   <li style="background: center no-repeat #bc874c url(images/image-03.jpg)"></li>
   <li style="background: center no-repeat #bc874c url(images/image-04.jpg)"></li>
</ul>
```

maybe creating a jquery function and pass the image url as a variable..let me know and I may be able to write something up for u

Comment: I want the onClick event to call the Lightbox, without using an "a" Element.